# ImportError: No module named textblob

Tags: python, atom-editor, textblob

I am using Atom and just getting started with Python. 
When I try to run this code:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

analysis = TextBlob("TextBlob sure looks like it has some interesting 
features")

print(analysis.tags)
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/bethwalsh/Documents/GitHub/automated-personas/py/test_001.py", 
line 1, in <module>
from textblob import TextBlob
ImportError: No module named textblob
```

I have tried to install textblob but still no change:

```
$ pip3 install textblob
Requirement already satisfied: textblob in 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages 
(0.15.1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the script with the same Python interpreter that you used to install `textblob`? This looks like macOS, so if you're just running it with `python myscript.py`, you're using Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7, not your Python 3.6. To use the latter, use `python3 myscript.py`. And similarly, if you're using Atom to run your script, you probably have to configure it to use `/usr/local/bin/python3` or `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3` instead of `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Also ran "which python3" and added the path to the top of my file "#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3". All working now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that worked thank you!

Had to install the **package atom-runner** and in the code change **python** -> **python3.**

Also ran

```
which python3
```

and added the path to the top of my py file:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python
```